# "which in turn" in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I'm writing a sentence with more than two causal steps. Something along the lines of

> The snow storm caused an severed power distribution lines in the area,
>   *which, in turn,* led to heating system not functioning.

What comes to mined is something like *in Folge* or *wiederum*, but I'd be happy to know for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There can be different possible translations for your phrase.

*Wiederum* is an almost literal translation of *in turn* in your example:

> Der Schneesturm verursachte eine unterbrochene Stromversorgung in dem Gebiet, was wiederum in einem nicht funktionierenden Heizungssystem resultierte.

If you want to separate the clauses more clearly, then you would use the suggestion of Thomas, but that would require a restructuring of the sentences:

> Der Schneesturm verursachte eine unterbrochene Stromversorgung in dem Gebiet, in Folge dessen funktionierte das Heizungssystem nicht mehr.

In that example you would better separate the clauses, as they can completely stand on their own:

> Der Schneesturm verursachte eine unterbrochene Stromversorgung in dem Gebiet. In Folge dessen funktionierte das Heizungssystem nicht mehr.

If you want to keep the relation of the clauses, then you would have to rewrite again:

> Der Schneesturm verursachte eine unterbrochene Stromversorgung in dem Gebiet, in deren Folge das Heizungssystem nicht mehr funktionierte.

You see, now the *dessen* has a relation to *Stromversorgung* and therefor takes its gender.

All examples are totally valid and usage depends on how strong the two events should be causally connected. For the strongest connection I would use the first example.

Comment: Very comprehensive, thank you. The last one is very interesting, because taking advantage of the more flexible German grammar with swapping sentences like this can be very effective!

Comment: @Torsten: Nice work, only a very small correction, for the last example you write it takes the case, but it is dependent on the gender.